Would an analyst be interested in quotient vector spaces?
I am trying to think of a justification of why one would be interested in quotient vector spaces from an analysis prespective. I know that from a geometric(/Topological) view, one maybe interested in the projective space corresponding to a space, and hence would want to do quotients. But, this is not particularly interesting from a person who does analysis as metric properties don't typically get preserved under quotients (specified no additional structure on the quotient).
This maybe enough to kill ones hope in seeing quotient vector spaces as in anyway useful in doing some sort of analysis. But maybe there are anyways some uses in analysis, but in different ways than I can think of, are there some such uses?

Analysts are interested in function spaces, and function spaces are vector spaces, so quotient spaces are natural analytic objects.

As one concrete example where these spaces are useful in proofs, you might think about the problem of detecting when an operator between Banach spaces has closed range. There is a result I know as the Closed Range Theorem that proves that one can equivalently look at the range of the adjoint operator. The proof I know of this theorem uses a lemma that says that $T^*$ is an isomorphic embedding if and only if $T$ is a quotient operator. The definition of this latter concept uses heavily the factorisation of the operator $T$ through $X / \ker T$.

What do you think is $L^p([0,1])$? Is this the space of $p$-integrable functions on $[0,1]$ or its quotient by the subspace of functions equal to zero a.e.?

I would say so, yes.

There are certainly nice properties in analysis that are preserved under quotients such as Completeness, Separability, Reflexivity, Uniform Convexity and Compactness. In fact, all of these are three-space properties.

Quotients characterize duals of subspaces: For a subspace  $Y \subset X$, the dual  $Y^* \simeq X^*/Y^\bot $ isometrically.

Any separable Banach space $X$  is a quotient of $\ell^1$ i.e. $X=\ell^1/V$ isometrically.

Factoring through the quotient space is a quite common trick; see the closed range theorem in Conway's book (1.10 Theorem). In fact, a bounded operator $T \colon X\to Y$ has closed range $R(T)$ if and only if  $\|Tx\|_T:=\|Tx\| + \|x+\ker T\|_{X/\ker T}$ is an equivalent norm on $R(T)$.

Quotients of $L^p$ spaces are generally an interesting topic (but I must admit I know little about it). An interesting problem is the $L^p$-extension problem: When does a bounded operator $T \colon L^p(0,1) \to L^p(0,1)$ extend to a bounded operator $T \colon L^p(0,1;X) \to L^p(0,1;X)$? Here $X$ is a Banach space. It turns out that a Banach space $X$ has this property for every $T$ if and only if $X$ is isomorphic to closed subspace of a quotient of an $L^p(S)$ space.


